# codeigniator project localhost to live server got errors in many sectors

Tags: database, codeigniter, server, localhost, libraries

I have made the news portal site using **codeignitor** framework it was working fine and while i have uploaded it to the server, i am getting errors like database errors in some sections and some are working fine. I have used authentication library also. **Do i have to give some permissions to the libraries i have used?** 
Any major changes than  changing  in config files and database files.
[image]

Comment: Have you set id to be auto increment?

Comment: Actually i have used the library(3rd party ) do i have to make id auto-increment while uploading to server ?? if it is working fine in localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came because `MYSQL 5.7` if your field `id` won't choose default value and then in `insert` query you not passing any value then it will through this error so set `id` default value null then it will work fine.

In details ->Goto `phpmyadmin` in then select `database` and then `login_attempts` table and then set `id` column default value to `null` or `some custom` value as you like

Comment: Thanks both setting default value null and auto increment  worked fine for me .

Comment: @shrijantripathi  please aprove and upvote the answer ,so any other can refere for same issue